# How to wrap instance yet forward calls to wrapped instance members?

Tags: fakeiteasy

Given I have a wrapped instance like this, where Resolve method injects dependencies

```
    var handler = this.Resolve<DeletePaymentCardHandler>();

    var wrapperHandler = A.Fake<DeletePaymentCardHandler>(
        o => o.Wrapping(handler));
    
    A.CallTo(() => wrapperHandler.EnsurePaymentCardCanBeDeleted(A<DeletePaymentCard>._, A<CancellationToken>._ ))
     .Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
    
    await wrapperHandler.Handle(command, CancellationToken.None);
```

Where 'Handle' method is implemented like this

```
public async Task Handle(DeletePaymentCard msg, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
     await this.EnsurePaymentCardCanBeDeleted(msg, cancellationToken);

     var instance = await this.repository.GetById<Domain.CustomerFundingSources>(msg.CustomerId, cancellationToken);

     instance.Process(msg);

     await this.repository.Save(instance);
}

public virtual async Task EnsurePaymentCardCanBeDeleted(DeletePaymentCard command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return Task.CompletedTask
}
```

What I am observing is that instead of this call in Handle calling injected repository it calls proxy created by FakeItEasy?

```
var instance = await this.repository.GetById<Domain.CustomerFundingSources>(msg.CustomerId, cancellationToken);
```

I thought point was to be able to intercept only calls to some methods and rest should call wrapped instance methods?
From documentation:

> "By default, calls to a wrapping fake that have not been explicitly
> configured will be forwarded to the wrapped object."

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to be completely sure without access to all the code of `DeletePaymentCardHandler`, but here's what it looks like to me:

`Handle` is not virtual, so will be executing the code in `DeletePaymentCardHandler`, bypassing FakeItEasy entirely.

In `Handle`, the `GetById` method is called on the `repository` *field* (accessing `repository` is not a method invocation, and FakeItEasy can't intercept field access), which will most likely have been initialized by the faked `DeletePaymentCardHandler` class's constructor.

If the `repository` field is initialized from a constructor argument, FakeItEasy [will have supplied a Dummy repository](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dummies/#how-fakeiteasy-uses-them) to satisfy that constructor argument. The repository type is very likely something that FakeItEasy can fake, so the value would be a Fake.

Thus, in `wrappedHandler.Handle`, the real `Handle` code is calling the fake `repository`.

If you want some other behaviour, then maybe the fake needs to be supplied the same repository as the wrapped handler. Or `Handle` could access the repository via a virtual property or method, which would be intercepted by FakeItEasy and forwarded to the wrapped handler, which would then access the repository supplied by the `Resolve` method.